# First http request in iOS networking is slow, subsequent requests are much faster

Tags: ios, node.js, android-volley, alamofire

I'm experiencing slow response times for my first http POST request to my server.

This happens both in Android and iOS networking libraries. (Volley on Android, and Alamofire in iOS).

First response is roughly 0.7s-0.9s, whereas subsequent requests are 0.2s.

I'm guessing this is due to the session being kept-alive by the server, therefore eliminating the need for establishing a new session on each request.

I figure I can make a dummy request when the app starts to start the session, but it doesn't seem very elegant.

I also control the server side (Node.js) so if any configuration needs to be done there I can also try it.

Answer (score 0):

Investigating a little further, I tried sending an https CONNECT request before issuing the first "real" POST request, and the behavior replicates.

After 30 seconds or so, the connection is dropped (probably at the iOS URLSession level, the load balancer is configured to keep connections as 60 seconds).

In theory this makes sense because setting up an https connection takes up several (12 total) packets and I'm on an inter continental connection.

So my solution is to send a CONNECT request when I expect the user to send a regular request.